# What is the equation of this curve?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

What would be the equation for the curve highlighted on the picture? I would google it, however I don't even know what should I search for, since I don't know the technical name of this kind of curves, any idea? or advise what should I look for?

[image]

Comment: If you determine scales, it would be precise sure.

Comment: I need it parametically

Comment: Can be a parabola $x=ay^2+by+c$.

Comment: @Maryam doing procedural modelling, so I want let user to specify parameters, so parametric equation is what I'm looking for

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Does parabola not have both side along one axis equal? (like mirror image?)

Comment: Only *some*, namely the symmetric parabolas. Choose the position of axes, pick three points on the parabola and you can determine $a,b,c$.

Comment: Yoy can cut asymmetrically a symmetric parabola.

Comment: However, this figure is graceful parabola, but a branch of the gamma can be used: $Gamma(x)~in~[-1,0]$

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla It is not a cut parabola, can you give me equasion of assymetric parabola, with takes 3 vertices as parameters?

Comment: Symmetric/asymmetric is relative. All the parabolas have an axis of symmetry that can be or not a coordinate axis. For the other question, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments suggested a parabola, but I found that to be a rather poor fit (blue).
*Edit:* I guess I might have made a mistake, the blue curve is a hyperbola. Parabola would have been worse, though.

Instead I'd go for an elliptical arc (green) or a Bézier curve (yellow, with given control points). I did all my curve fitting manually, though, no automatic optimization involved.

[image: Snapshot]

*Edit:* Since [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/654254/35416) by [Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/98199/martin-blas-perez-pinilla) suggests not only a parabola, but one with a horizontal axis, here is the best fit I could manage for that. This time, the parabola is in green, its directrix and focus in blue. The endpoints of the curve in particular seem to fit rather poorly, which is why I'd still prefer the ellipse.

[image: Parabola fit]

Answer (score 0):

This is valid for parabolas $y=ax^2+bx+c$ and $x=ay^2+by+c$. Suppose the first case. Let be $(x_1,y1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_3,y_3)$ the three points. You have the following linear system with three unknowns $a,b,c$:
$$y_1=ax_1^2+bx_1+c,$$
$$y_2=ax_2^2+bx_2+c,$$
$$y_3=ax_3^2+bx_3+c.$$
Solve it. Done.